# XSLT: Set the background colour of cell when the task is overdue

Tags: 2010, xslt

I currently have this XSLT added to my list (snippet):

```
...
<xsl:param name="Today">CurrentDate</xsl:param>
<xsl:template name="FieldRef_printTableCell_EcbAllowed.Due_x0020_Date0" match="FieldRef[@Name='Due_x0020_Date0']" mode="printTableCellEcbAllowed" ddwrt:dvt_mode="body" ddwrt:ghost="" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="." />
    <xsl:param name="class" />
    <td>
        <xsl:attribute name="style">
            <xsl:if test="ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string($thisNode/@Due_x0020_Date0))) &gt; ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string($Today)))" ddwrt:cf_explicit="1">
                    background-color: #FF0000;
            </xsl:if>
...
```

However, this doesn't work and turns all the non-empty cells in my overdue column to red. What am I missing here?

If it helps, the dates in the column are in this format: `m/d/yy`

I'm trying to turn the cell red if the task is overdue (based on today's date)

---

UPDATE: The HTML generated for that particular `td` is as follows by the way:

```
<td style="background-color: #FF0000;" class="ms-vb2">
  <nobr>7/29/2014</nobr>
</td>
```

I'm not sure if the `<nobr>` tags have something to do with it.

Here's the [complete XSLT file](http://pastebin.com/8dpv6SEB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it to work!
In my case, for some reason, there is something wrong with the `$Today` variable so instead I did this and it worked for me:

```
<xsl:if test="ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string($thisNode/@Due_x0020_Date0)))
                  &lt;= ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string(ddwrt:Today())))">
  background-color: #FF0000;
</xsl:if>
```

Note that I explicitly used `ddwrt:Today()` instead of `$Today`.

I'm sure Chris and cubanGuy's answers would have worked had my web part been a data view one instead of a list view. Thanks for you guys' help! It gave me a lot of hints.

Answer (score 1):

I have used something similar to what you need:

My XSLT:

```
<xsl:attribute name="style">
<xsl:if test="ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string(@Test))) &lt;  ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string($Today)))">background-color: #FF0000;</xsl:if>
</xsl:attribute>
```

Your XSLT:

```
<xsl:attribute name="style">
<xsl:if   test="ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string($thisNode/@Due_x0020_Date0))) &gt;    ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string($Today)))" ddwrt:cf_explicit="1">
    background-color: #FF0000;
</xsl:if>
```

Pretty much the only major difference I see is that I din't use "$thisNode". By the way @Test refers to Test Due Date.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Now none of the cells have a red background. I've updated the question in case it helps more.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your filter has  `&gt;` (>) instead of `&lt;`(<)

Wouldn't an overdue task be something in the past and therefore less than today's date?

My xsl looks like CubanGuy's

```
<td class="ms-vb">
            <xsl:attribute name="style">
                <xsl:if test="ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string(@duedate))) &lt; ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string($Today)))">background-color: #FF0000;</xsl:if>
            </xsl:attribute>

            <xsl:value-of select="@duedate"/>
        </td>
```

and produces this result (based off today, 9/4):
[image: example]

and here is html

```
<td class="ms-vb" style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">
  Text - 9/1/2014
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Could you take a look at the pastebin link I've posted in my question? I'm placing this code in the `XSL Link` parameter of the list view (linked to an external file, not pasted directly to the field). That's probably why I need `$thisNode` to get anything to get highlighted at all.

Comment: Did you try changing to `<` in your comparison for date or am I missing the reason for `>`? Other than that I do not have a lot of experience with item link. I incorrectly assumed this was for a DVWP, so that's about the limit of my usefulness (sorry)